# Adaptions sbl-style

Tags: biblatex

I use biblatex-sbl and this is my current result:

> Gehrke, Hans-Joachim. Geschichte der Antike. Ein Studienbuch. 2. Aufl.
>   Stuttgart, 2019.

In German bibliography, it is quite usual to quote the edition (in German "Auflage") not as "2. Aufl.", but the number of the edition in superscript in front of the publication date, such as:

> Gehrke, Hans-Joachim. Geschichte der Antike. Ein Studienbuch.
>   Stuttgart, 22019.

Can sb. help me in this case? Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@mvbook{Gehrke.19,
  author = {Gehrke, Hans-Joachim},
  title = {Geschichte der Antike. Ein Studienbuch},
  location = {Stuttgart},
edition = {2},
  date = {2019}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[style=sbl,ibidtracker=false,idemtracker=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Filler text \autocite{Gehrke.19}.
Filler text \autocite{Gehrke.19}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to patch the `(cite:)book`, `cite:commentary`, `(cite:)suppbook`, and `(cite:)incollection` drivers to remove the printing of the edition in its usual place, adjust the date printing macro to include the edition, and then change the format of the edition.

Hopefully, this won't have any unintended side effects.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@mvbook{Gehrke.19,
  author = {Gehrke, Hans-Joachim},
  title = {Geschichte der Antike. Ein Studienbuch},
  location = {Stuttgart},
  edition = {2},
  date = {2019}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[style=sbl,ibidtracker=false,idemtracker=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:book}
  {\newunit\printfield{edition}}
  {}{}{}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:commentary}
  {\newunit\printfield{edition}}
  {}{}{}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:suppbook}
  {\newunit\printfield{edition}}
  {}{}{}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:incollection}
  {\newunit\printfield{edition}}
  {}{}{}
\xpatchbibdriver{book}
  {\newunit\printfield{edition}}
  {}{}{}
\xpatchbibdriver{suppbook}
  {\newunit\printfield{edition}}
  {}{}{}
\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
  {\newunit\printfield{edition}}
  {}{}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{date}{%
  \printfield{edition}%
  \printdate
  \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \printfield{pubstate}}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Filler text \autocite{Gehrke.19}.
Filler text \autocite{Gehrke.19}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: Actually, I have checked it again and now, there is an unintended side effect in my full document: The bibliography works well, but in the notes it is: KRAUSE, JENS-UWE: „Die Spätantike (284­565 n. Chr.)“, in: GEHRKE, HANS-JOACHIM/SCHNEIDER, HELMUTH (Hgg.):
Geschichte der Antike. Ein Studienbuch, 5 , Stuttgart 5 2019, 429–499. Both "5" are in superscript. Is there another way to solve this issue without such unintended side effects?

Comment: @anonym, can you please ask a new question with as MWE? I need to see the bib entry. You can receive this question in the new question for context.