# Adaptions sbl-style II

Tags: biblatex

I use biblatex-sbl and this is my current result:

> Gehrke, Hans-Joachim. Geschichte der Antike. Ein Studienbuch. 2. Aufl.
>   Stuttgart, 2019.

In German bibliography, it is quite usual to quote the edition (in German "Auflage") not as "2. Aufl.", but the number of the edition in superscript in front of the publication date, such as:

> Gehrke, Hans-Joachim. Geschichte der Antike. Ein Studienbuch.
>   Stuttgart, 22019.

A few days ago, I received an answer here: [Adaptions sbl-style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503804/adaptions-sbl-style)

However, there were some complications; it seems to me that the cause of it should be this:

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{cite:incollection}{%
  \ifentrytype{seminarpaper}
    {}
    {\toggletrue{inentrytype}}%
  \usebibmacro{citeindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \iftoggle{blx@usefullcite}
    {}
    {\let\ifciteseen\@firstoftwo}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \ifciteseen
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{byauthor/byeditor+others/bytranslator+others}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{in:}%
     \iffieldundef{booktitle}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{bookeditor}%
        \usebibmacro{booktitle}%
        \newunit
        \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
        \newunit
        \usebibmacro{bybookauthor/bybookeditor+others/bybooktranslator+others}%
        \newunit}%
     \usebibmacro{volume+partof}%
     \iffieldundef{maintitle}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{maineditor}%
        \usebibmacro{maintitle}%
        \newunit
        \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
        \newunit
        \usebibmacro{bymainauthor/bymaineditor+others/bymaintranslator+others}}%
     \newunit
     \printfield{edition}%
     \newunit
     \printfield{volumes}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{shortseries+number}%
     \newunit
     \printfield{note}%
     \usebibmacro{parens+publisher+location+date}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{ebook}%
     \newunit
     \printfield{addendum}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{volume+part+pages}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{isbn}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
  \toggletrue{inentrytype}%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \ifentrytype{classictext}
    {\usebibmacro{byauthor}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}
    {\usebibmacro{byauthor/byeditor+others/bytranslator+others}}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \iffieldundef{booktitle}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{bookeditor}%
     \usebibmacro{booktitle}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{bybookauthor/bybookeditor+others/bybooktranslator+others}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+partof}%
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{maineditor}%
     \usebibmacro{maintitle}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{bymainauthor/bymaineditor+others/bymaintranslator+others}}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{shortseries+number}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{ebook}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+part+pages}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{isbn}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \ifboolexpr{
    togl {relatedseen}
    or
    not togl {bbx:related}
  }
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}
```

Here is my MWE:

```
\RequirePackage[patch]{kvoptions} 
\documentclass[openany]{book} %headsepline

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@mvbook{Gehrke.19,
  author = {Gehrke, Hans-Joachim},
  title = {Geschichte der Antike. Ein Studienbuch},
  location = {Stuttgart},
  edition = {2},
  date = {2019}
}

@incollection{Krause.19,
 author={Krause, Jens-Uwe},
 gender = {sm},
 title={Die Spätantike (284-565 n. Chr.)},
 editor = {Gehrke, Hans-Joachim and Schneider, Helmuth},
 date = {2019},
 booktitle = {Geschichte der Antike. Ein Studienbuch},
 location = {Stuttgart},
 keywords = {sekundaer},
 pages={429--499},
 edition={5},
}

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{babel} %Kommentar 


\setmainlanguage[variant=new]{ngerman}


\setmainfont{Times New Roman}


\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes}
%\usepackage[german=guillement]{csquotes} 
\usepackage[style=sbl,backend=biber,sblfootnotes=false,ibidpage=true,sorting=nyvt,url=false,isbn=false,doi=false,clearlang=false,uniquename=false]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\usepackage{xpatch}


\DeclareBibliographyDriver{cite:incollection}{%
  \ifentrytype{seminarpaper}
    {}
    {\toggletrue{inentrytype}}%
  \usebibmacro{citeindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \iftoggle{blx@usefullcite}
    {}
    {\let\ifciteseen\@firstoftwo}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \ifciteseen
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{byauthor/byeditor+others/bytranslator+others}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{in:}%
     \iffieldundef{booktitle}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{bookeditor}%
        \usebibmacro{booktitle}%
        \newunit
        \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
        \newunit
        \usebibmacro{bybookauthor/bybookeditor+others/bybooktranslator+others}%
        \newunit}%
     \usebibmacro{volume+partof}%
     \iffieldundef{maintitle}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{maineditor}%
        \usebibmacro{maintitle}%
        \newunit
        \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
        \newunit
        \usebibmacro{bymainauthor/bymaineditor+others/bymaintranslator+others}}%
     \newunit
     \printfield{edition}%
     \newunit
     \printfield{volumes}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{shortseries+number}%
     \newunit
     \printfield{note}%
     \usebibmacro{parens+publisher+location+date}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{ebook}%
     \newunit
     \printfield{addendum}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{volume+part+pages}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{isbn}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
  \toggletrue{inentrytype}%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \ifentrytype{classictext}
    {\usebibmacro{byauthor}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}
    {\usebibmacro{byauthor/byeditor+others/bytranslator+others}}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \iffieldundef{booktitle}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{bookeditor}%
     \usebibmacro{booktitle}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{bybookauthor/bybookeditor+others/bybooktranslator+others}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+partof}%
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{maineditor}%
     \usebibmacro{maintitle}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{bymainauthor/bymaineditor+others/bymaintranslator+others}}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{shortseries+number}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{ebook}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+part+pages}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{isbn}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \ifboolexpr{
    togl {relatedseen}
    or
    not togl {bbx:related}
  }
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}


\xpatchbibdriver{book}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {}
  {}


\renewcommand*{\subtitlepunct}{\addperiod\space} % Punkt zw Titel und Subtitel in Bibliogr.
\renewcommand*{\sqspace}{} % kein Abstand bei Seitenzahl mit "f." 

\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{#1} % Buchtitel nur normal - ohne Formatierung
\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{title}{#1} % Buchtitel nur normal - ohne Formatierung
\DeclareFieldFormat[review]{title}{#1} % Buchtitel nur normal - ohne Formatierung
\DeclareFieldFormat*{journaltitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{maintitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{booktitle}{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{shorttitle}{#1} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{shortbooktitle}{#1} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{shortmaintitle}{#1} 

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given} % vorher last-first in Klammern
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{sortname}



\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addslash\space} 
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim} 

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc} 
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}{\textsc} 
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}{\textsc} 
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamesuffix}{\textsc} 

%%%%%% Verursacher nr. 1 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}} 
%\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace} 
%%%%%% Verursacher %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addslash\space} 
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim} 

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc} 
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}{\textsc} 
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}{\textsc} 
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamesuffix}{\textsc} 


%%\renewbibmacro*{editor+others}{% 
  %%\ifboolexpr{ 
   %% test \ifuseeditor 
   %% and 
   %% not test {\ifnameundef{editor}} 
  %%} 
    %%{\ifciteseen{% 
      %% \usebibmacro{ifidemused} 
       %%  {} 
        %% {\printnames[labelname]{editor}}% 
    %% }{\renewcommand*{\namedashpunct}{\addcomma\space}% 
      %% \usebibmacro{dashcheck} 
        %% {\bibnamedash} 
        %% {\usebibmacro{ifidemused} 
         %%   {} 
           %% {\printnames{editor}% 
             %%\usebibmacro{savehash}}}% 
      %% \setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}% 
       %%\usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}% 
      %% \usebibmacro{withname}{editor}% 
     %%}% 
     %%\clearname{editor}} 
    %%{}} 


\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
  reprint = {ND:}
}

    % Put reprint information in parentheses and change beginning punctuation to a
% space
\newcommand*{\begrelateddelimreprint}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{related:reprint}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

% Set \newunitpunct to comma and remove parentheses around publication info
\renewbibmacro*{related:reprint}[1]{%
  \entrydata*{#1}{%
    \usedriver
      {\renewbibmacro*{related:init}{}%
       \renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}%
       \renewbibmacro*{parens+publisher+location+date}{%
         \newunit
         \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}}}
      {\ifbibliography
         {\thefield{entrytype}}
         {cite:\thefield{entrytype}}}}}

% use family, given and change \newunitpunct to a point just for related
% entries (I have serious misgivings about this as it seems very
% inconsistent.)
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretobibmacro{cite}
  {\iffieldequalstr{relatedtype}{reprint}
     {\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}%
      \renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addperiod\space}}
     {}}
  {}
  {}



\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{ 
  editors = {Hgg\adddot}, 
} 


\renewbibmacro*{parens+publisher+location+date}{% 
\newunit
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}% 
  \iffieldequalstr{relatedtype}{reprint} 
    {\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addsemicolon\space}% 
     \newunit 
     \usebibmacro{related:init}% 
     \usebibmacro{related}% 
     \global\toggletrue{relatedseen}} 
    {}} 

\renewbibmacro*{origpublisher+location+date}{% 
  \printlist{origlocation}% 
  \setunit*{\addspace}% 
  \usebibmacro{origdate}% 
  \newunit} 

\newbibmacro*{real+publisher+location+date}{% 
  \printlist{location}% 
  \iffieldundef{howpublished} 
    {} 
    {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}% 
     \printfield{howpublished}}% 
  \setunit*{\addspace}% 
  \usebibmacro{date}% 
  \newunit} 


\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{% 
  \ifboolexpr{ 
    not test {\iffieldundef{origpublisher}} 
    or 
    not test {\iffieldundef{origlocation}} 
    or 
    not test {\iffieldundef{origyear}} 
  } 
    {\usebibmacro{origpublisher+location+date}% 
     \setunit{\addspace}% 
     \printtext[parens]{% 
       \bibstring{reprint}% 
       \setunit{\addspace}% 
       \usebibmacro{real+publisher+location+date}}} 
    {\usebibmacro{real+publisher+location+date}}} 

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions[inlexicon]{% 
  skipbib=false, 
} 

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inlexicon}{% 
  \usebibmacro{begentry}% 
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}% 
  \newunit 
  \usebibmacro{title}% 
  \newunit 
  \printfield{note}% 
  \newunit 
  \usebibmacro{xrefshortmaintitle+xrefshortbooktitle}% 
  \newunit 
  \usebibmacro{volume+pages}% 
  \newunit 
  \printfield{addendum}% 
  \usebibmacro{finentry}% 
}

\xpatchbibdriver{cite:book}
  {\newunit\printfield{edition}}
  {}{}{}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:commentary}
  {\newunit\printfield{edition}}
  {}{}{}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:suppbook}
  {\newunit\printfield{edition}}
  {}{}{}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:incollection}
  {\newunit\printfield{edition}}
  {}{}{}
\xpatchbibdriver{book}
  {\newunit\printfield{edition}}
  {}{}{}
  \xpatchbibdriver{suppbook}
  {\newunit\printfield{edition}}
  {}{}{}
\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
  {\newunit\printfield{edition}}
  {}{}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{date}{%
  \printfield{edition}%
  \printdate
  \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \printfield{pubstate}}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Filler text \autocite{Gehrke.19}.
Filler text \autocite{Gehrke.19}.
Filler text \autocite{Krause.19}.
Filler text \autocite{Krause.19}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MWE does not compile as there are a few bugs.

You load `babel`, but then use the `polyglossia` macro `\setmainlanguage`.

You just want `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` and remove `\setmainlanguage[variant=new]{ngerman}` (which I don't think is valid anyway).

You also use `\setmainfont{Times New Roman}`, but you don't load `fontspec` which defines this macro.

In your redefinition of the `incollection` driver you have `\usebibmacro{bookeditor}`, but this macro is not defined in `biblatex` or `biblatex-sbl`, so an error is generated. You need to define the `bookeditor` bibmacro.

Finally, the reason that you are getting the edition printed twice is because you have redefined the `cite:incollection` driver, but without surrounding your redefinition with `\makeatletter` … `\makeatother`. Your redefinition contains `\let\ifciteseen\@firstoftwo`. The `\@firstoftwo` is interpreted wrongly because `@` has the wrong catcode.

This also means that the patch lower down which tries to remove the edition fails.

Since you are completely redefining the `incollection` drivers, just leave the edition out of your redefinition and you don't need to patch below.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@mvbook{Gehrke.19,
  author = {Gehrke, Hans-Joachim},
  title = {Geschichte der Antike. Ein Studienbuch},
  location = {Stuttgart},
  edition = {2},
  date = {2019}
}

@incollection{Krause.19,
 author={Krause, Jens-Uwe},
 gender = {sm},
 title={Die Spätantike (284-565 n. Chr.)},
 editor = {Gehrke, Hans-Joachim and Schneider, Helmuth},
 date = {2019},
 booktitle = {Geschichte der Antike. Ein Studienbuch},
 location = {Stuttgart},
 keywords = {sekundaer},
 pages={429--499},
 edition={5},
}

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=sbl,backend=biber,sblfootnotes=false,ibidpage=true,sorting=nyvt,url=false,isbn=false,doi=false,clearlang=false,uniquename=false]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\newbibmacro*{bookeditor}{%
  \printnames{bookeditor}}

\makeatletter
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{cite:incollection}{%
  \ifentrytype{seminarpaper}
    {}
    {\toggletrue{inentrytype}}%
  \usebibmacro{citeindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \iftoggle{blx@usefullcite}
    {}
    {\let\ifciteseen\@firstoftwo}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \ifciteseen
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{byauthor/byeditor+others/bytranslator+others}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{in:}%
     \iffieldundef{booktitle}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{bookeditor}%
        \usebibmacro{booktitle}%
        \newunit
        \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
        \newunit
        \usebibmacro{bybookauthor/bybookeditor+others/bybooktranslator+others}%
        \newunit}%
     \usebibmacro{volume+partof}%
     \iffieldundef{maintitle}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{maineditor}%
        \usebibmacro{maintitle}%
        \newunit
        \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
        \newunit
        \usebibmacro{bymainauthor/bymaineditor+others/bymaintranslator+others}}%
     \newunit
     \printfield{volumes}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{shortseries+number}%
     \newunit
     \printfield{note}%
     \usebibmacro{parens+publisher+location+date}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{ebook}%
     \newunit
     \printfield{addendum}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{volume+part+pages}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{isbn}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
\makeatother

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
  \toggletrue{inentrytype}%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \ifentrytype{classictext}
    {\usebibmacro{byauthor}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}
    {\usebibmacro{byauthor/byeditor+others/bytranslator+others}}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \iffieldundef{booktitle}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{bookeditor}%
     \usebibmacro{booktitle}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{bybookauthor/bybookeditor+others/bybooktranslator+others}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+partof}%
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{maineditor}%
     \usebibmacro{maintitle}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{bymainauthor/bymaineditor+others/bymaintranslator+others}}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{shortseries+number}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{ebook}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+part+pages}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{isbn}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \ifboolexpr{
    togl {relatedseen}
    or
    not togl {bbx:related}
  }
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}


\xpatchbibdriver{book}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {}
  {}


\renewcommand*{\subtitlepunct}{\addperiod\space} % Punkt zw Titel und Subtitel in Bibliogr.
\renewcommand*{\sqspace}{} % kein Abstand bei Seitenzahl mit "f." 

\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{#1} % Buchtitel nur normal - ohne Formatierung
\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{title}{#1} % Buchtitel nur normal - ohne Formatierung
\DeclareFieldFormat[review]{title}{#1} % Buchtitel nur normal - ohne Formatierung
\DeclareFieldFormat*{journaltitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{maintitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{booktitle}{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{shorttitle}{#1} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{shortbooktitle}{#1} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{shortmaintitle}{#1} 

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given} % vorher last-first in Klammern
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{sortname}



\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addslash\space} 
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim} 

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc} 
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}{\textsc} 
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}{\textsc} 
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamesuffix}{\textsc} 

%%%%%% Verursacher nr. 1 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}} 
%\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace} 
%%%%%% Verursacher %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addslash\space} 
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim} 

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc} 
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}{\textsc} 
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}{\textsc} 
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamesuffix}{\textsc} 



\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
  reprint = {ND:}
}

    % Put reprint information in parentheses and change beginning punctuation to a
% space
\newcommand*{\begrelateddelimreprint}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{related:reprint}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

% Set \newunitpunct to comma and remove parentheses around publication info
\renewbibmacro*{related:reprint}[1]{%
  \entrydata*{#1}{%
    \usedriver
      {\renewbibmacro*{related:init}{}%
       \renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}%
       \renewbibmacro*{parens+publisher+location+date}{%
         \newunit
         \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}}}
      {\ifbibliography
         {\thefield{entrytype}}
         {cite:\thefield{entrytype}}}}}

% use family, given and change \newunitpunct to a point just for related
% entries (I have serious misgivings about this as it seems very
% inconsistent.)
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretobibmacro{cite}
  {\iffieldequalstr{relatedtype}{reprint}
     {\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}%
      \renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addperiod\space}}
     {}}
  {}
  {}



\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{ 
  editors = {Hgg\adddot}, 
} 


\renewbibmacro*{parens+publisher+location+date}{% 
\newunit
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}% 
  \iffieldequalstr{relatedtype}{reprint} 
    {\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addsemicolon\space}% 
     \newunit 
     \usebibmacro{related:init}% 
     \usebibmacro{related}% 
     \global\toggletrue{relatedseen}} 
    {}} 

\renewbibmacro*{origpublisher+location+date}{% 
  \printlist{origlocation}% 
  \setunit*{\addspace}% 
  \usebibmacro{origdate}% 
  \newunit} 

\newbibmacro*{real+publisher+location+date}{% 
  \printlist{location}% 
  \iffieldundef{howpublished} 
    {} 
    {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}% 
     \printfield{howpublished}}% 
  \setunit*{\addspace}% 
  \usebibmacro{date}% 
  \newunit} 


\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{% 
  \ifboolexpr{ 
    not test {\iffieldundef{origpublisher}} 
    or 
    not test {\iffieldundef{origlocation}} 
    or 
    not test {\iffieldundef{origyear}} 
  } 
    {\usebibmacro{origpublisher+location+date}% 
     \setunit{\addspace}% 
     \printtext[parens]{% 
       \bibstring{reprint}% 
       \setunit{\addspace}% 
       \usebibmacro{real+publisher+location+date}}} 
    {\usebibmacro{real+publisher+location+date}}} 

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions[inlexicon]{% 
  skipbib=false, 
} 

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inlexicon}{% 
  \usebibmacro{begentry}% 
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}% 
  \newunit 
  \usebibmacro{title}% 
  \newunit 
  \printfield{note}% 
  \newunit 
  \usebibmacro{xrefshortmaintitle+xrefshortbooktitle}% 
  \newunit 
  \usebibmacro{volume+pages}% 
  \newunit 
  \printfield{addendum}% 
  \usebibmacro{finentry}% 
}

\xpatchbibdriver{cite:book}
  {\newunit\printfield{edition}}
  {}{}{}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:commentary}
  {\newunit\printfield{edition}}
  {}{}{}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:suppbook}
  {\newunit\printfield{edition}}
  {}{}{}
\xpatchbibdriver{book}
  {\newunit\printfield{edition}}
  {}{}{}
  \xpatchbibdriver{suppbook}
  {\newunit\printfield{edition}}
  {}{}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{date}{%
  \printfield{edition}%
  \printdate
  \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \printfield{pubstate}}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Filler text \autocite{Gehrke.19}.
Filler text \autocite{Gehrke.19}.
Filler text \autocite{Krause.19}.
Filler text \autocite{Krause.19}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]